# how to read Mysql json column to an embedded struct using Gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to read columns to an embedded struct usng gorm, the table has a Json column and I would like to read it a defined struct. How can I achieve this one ??

```
type Permissions struct {
   // all other columns 
   Rules []Rule // this is saved as a json column in db  
}

type Rule struct {
  // embedded columns here too 
}
```

Comment: You would need to have a `string` in your gorm struct for the json column and then unmarshal the json into the according struct.

Answer (score 2):

[Custom data types](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Implements-Customized-Data-Type) are supported, you would just need to implement the `Scanner` and `Valuer` interfaces for your custom type. It could look something like this:

```
func (r *Rule) Scan(value interface{}) error {
  val, ok := value.([]byte)
  if !ok {
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("Failed to unmarshal string value:", value))
  }

  return json.Unmarshal([]byte(val), r)
}

func (r Rule) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
  val, err := json.Marshal(&r)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  
  return val, nil
}
```