# How to specify a text column's value as a string union?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a struct `Document`:

```
type Document struct {
    ID               entity.EntityID
    Type             string
    ContentType      files.MIMEType
    URL              string
    UploadedByUserID entity.EntityID
    CreatedAt        time.Time
}

type MIMEType string

const (
    MIMETypeJPG MIMEType = "image/jpeg"
    MIMETypePDF MIMEType = "application/pdf"
    MIMETypePNG MIMEType = "image/png"
    MIMETypeTXT MIMEType = "text/plain"
)
```

It maps to a `documents` table where the `ContentType` column is of type `varchar(1024)`:

```
create table documents(
    id bigint not null default nextval('documents_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
    url varchar(1024) not null,
    type varchar(1024) not null,
    content_type varchar(1024) not null,
    uploaded_by_user_id bigint,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
);
```

`Create(&d)` where `d` is a `Document` instance gives me an error:

```
[2.530ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO "documents" ("type","content_type","url","uploaded_by_user_id","created_at") VALUES ('other_freight','image/png','https://lateralline-documents-dev.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/doc-other_freight-2021_08_25__11_15_13_379569000.png','253608954016301056','2021-08-25 11:15:13.82') RETURNING "id"
interface conversion: interface {} is files.MIMEType, not string
```

I want to tell gorm that when I read and write the `documents.content_type` field it is not just an arbitrary string, it should be a `files.MIMEType` value. Is there a way to do this? I've seen this functionality in other ORMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the [custom types](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Implements-Customized-Data-Type) in `go-gorm` (or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917049/how-to-read-mysql-json-column-to-an-embedded-struct-using-gorm/68917653#68917653) answer).

In short, you would need to implement the `Scanner` and `Valuer` interfaces for your `MIMEType` struct.

```
func (m *MIMEType) Scan(value interface{}) error {
  val, ok := value.(string)
  if !ok {
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("Failed to unmarshal string value:", value))
  }
  
  *m = MIMEType(val)
  return nil
}

func (m MIMEType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
  return string(m), nil
}
```